# API fetch issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm trying to fetch data from the api database but I'm getting this error:

> [Unhandled promise rejection: SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "object"].

I'm not sure where I'm making a mistake.

```
    import React, { useReducer, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Button, FlatList, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
    import {getNews} from '../API/fetchData';



    export function NewsScreen() {
        const [news, setNews] = useState ([]);


        useEffect(() => {
            getDetail()
        }, [0]);

    const getDetail = async () => {
        const News = await getNews(0);
        setNews(News)

    }

    return (
        <View>
            <Text>jj</Text>
        </View>
    )

    };


    export default NewsScreen;
```

Comment: can you please paste `getNews` code too?

Comment: Or at least the result of `getNews(0)`.

Comment: what you actually want is the actual network request; it looks like the web service is returning invalid JSON data.

Comment: I'm trying to fetch data from a database, I used the configuration as it was in the documentation, it was working yesterday like there was a log of a successful post request. Now nothing comes in. I think you right about invalid JSON data.

Comment: fetch and retrieve it as .text() instead of .json()  and view the output.  also check the network panel in chrome dev tools